# Return promise that immediately resolves

Tags: promise

I need my function to return a promise that resolves right after the promise it creates has been returned to the function that calls it.

Right now I have this:

```
class BrandsDataFetcher extends BaseDataFetcher {
    getBrands() {
        const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());  
        p.then(() => {
            return {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
        }); 
        return p; 
    }
}
```

However, in my function that calls this function, the data it gets back is undefined:

```
const brandsDataFetcher = new BrandsDataFetcher();
return brandsDataFetcher.getBrands()
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(typeof(data));   // 'undefined'
```

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the original promise, not the return value from `then`:

```
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
const q = p.then(() => {
    return {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
});        // q would return your object...
return p;  // but you return the original p instead!
```

The idiomatic way to do this is with [`Promise.resolve(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```
class BrandsDataFetcher extends BaseDataFetcher {
    getBrands() {
        return Promise.resolve({'a': 1, 'b': 2}); 
    }
}
```